# How to validate form using AJAX Json

Tags: json, ajax, model-view-controller

```
`function SaveDetails() {
//  var frmData = $('#frmSaveDetails').serializeObject();
var form = $("#frmSaveDetails");
var frmdata = SerializeObject("frmSaveDetails");`
```

`$.ajax("/Home/SaveDetails", {
            type: 'POST',
            data: frmdata,
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                if (!result.success) {
                    //What to write here?
                    }

                }
            },
            error: function () {
                //alert('An error occurred, please try again.');
            }
        });
}`

How to return JSON response and show error in form to respective controls .I want No alert msgs. please help ..thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery ajax but somewhat in different way as by using its library as https://jqueryvalidation.org/   here you get multiple validation related syntax for validation handling.

For more detail study you go with this page...

https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: Yup I guess Using rules and messeges would be the best way to validate and that wont take me to server side . If you have any other way please suggest